# How to get 1/3 of the total height of a page with Jquery and show a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, height

I am trying to get the total height of my page with .height () in jquery, in which I need a button to return to the top at the end of the first 1/3 of the total height of the page. As well as I show it in the following graph (the button has **position: fixed**):

[image]

I did it in the following way but I see that the button appears near the bottom of my page, how could I do it ?:

```
var doc_height = $(document).height();
var third = (doc_height / 3);

//Go top button
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > third) {
    $('.scroll-top').fadeIn('slow');

  } else {
    $('.scroll-top').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});

$('.scroll-top').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);
});
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what is the objective. Do you want to place your button at 1/3 of height of the page and make it stick ? If yes then you need to add `top: 33%` to the fixed button.  `position: fixed`  make element stick to the window, so it will always be positioned to the window,  Javascript has nothing to do with it, please add css and html and describe what is desired outcome. If you only want to position the button in container then your button for sure can't have `position: fixed`

Comment: What I need is to obtain 1/3 of the total height of the entire page, then in the first 1/3 the button should appear.